# Use of the Jeffreys prior in multidimensional models

Tags: bayesian, prior, jeffreys-prior

Suppose a model,

$$x_{i} \sim N(\theta_{i}, \phi), \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,n$$

Furthermore, suppose the variance parameter, $\phi$, is some known constant.

The multidimensional Jeffreys prior is defined as,

$$\pi(\vec{\theta}) \propto \sqrt{\text{det}I(\vec{\theta})}$$

where $\text{det}I(\vec{\theta)}$ is the determinant of the multidimensional Fisher information.

Can a multidimensional Jeffreys prior be used to formulate a prior distribution for the posterior distribution, $p(\vec{\theta}|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$?

Comment: Are the $x_i$ independent from each others?

Comment: @peuhp Yes, I meant to say that the $x_{i}$ are assumed to be i.i.d.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. How can they be i.i.d. if they are drawn from different distributions?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right to be confused. That was a typo (bad habit, I'm afraid) - they're *not* identically distributed, just independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a multidimensional Jeffreys prior be used to formulate a prior distribution for the posterior distribution, p(θ⃗ |x1,…,xn)?

Yes, but it's usually not recommended to use Jeffreys prior for anything other than a single parameter model. The go-to approach for multidimensional cases is the **Reference prior**. Reference priors maximize the K-L divergence between the prior and the posterior averaged over the sufficient statistic distribution, so that we learn as much as possible from the data. A strong introduction and justification for Reference priors can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0156.pdf). A more approachable introduction is available in [this lecture](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture7.pdf) accompanied by [this lecture](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture8.pdf). If it's comforting at all, for single parameter models the Reference prior works out to be the Jeffreys prior in each case.

Answer (score 0):

If the $x_i$ are independent from each others, I would say that the Fisher information is diagonal and you will obtain a product of the univariate Jeffreys prior which in this case are the uniform ones. So your "multivariate prior" consists of :
$$
p_{\vec{\Theta}}(\vec{\theta}) \propto 1
$$

Comment: That's what I've ended up with, but is this a valid approach to use for the model described? In other words, is there anything theoretically invalid about using the multivariate Jeffreys prior under the conditions described above?

Comment: @user9171 I am not an expert but I would feel confortable with doing that. To my opinion, the main question is more why building a kind of "full" model for independent variables? but I can't answer this question without understanding the context. Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree. I'm just curious if it's valid theoretically. Thanks a million!